# Trying to add text to a video file and save it as an mpeg to be played in a slide show

Tags: mpeg

I have been asked to create a slide for a viewsonic slideshow player that has a rotating diamond at the bottom, and "Your Diamond Store" above.
I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this with what I have and this is way out of my normal scope.
I have adobe cs4 suite and standard apple software.  Can anyone please help?
Thanks!!

Comment: You don't mention the model, but if "slideshow player" = "Digital Picture Frame", none of the ones on their website support video.

Answer (score 1):

Either After Effects or Premiere will do this for you no problem.  I'd probably use After Effects for simplicity since it is easier to understand the layers there.  Either use a text effect or use Illustrator to make the text a bit nicer and import it in as a layer in After Effects.  Position the video that it is playing over as the bottom layer then import the text layer and position it over the background as necessary.

For the rotating diamond, you would need a rotating diamond that has a transparent background to the layer.  This is easiest to do with 3d graphics software, though you could also do it by rotating an actual diamond and keying out the background from around it.

On the other hand, the best looking approach (since a diamond refracts the surroundings) would be to bring it in to a professional 3d package and use the video as an environment map for the refraction to be correct and then export it as a series of images with alpha that can be composited back in as a source in After Effects.  Since the diamond will look like it is refracting the image it is over, it will be far more believable as a diamond in the scene.

I'm not sure if Blender (the most popular free 3d software) can support environment maps or not, but if it can, that would be your best bet for approaching that.  (Sadly, I use commercial 3D software so I've never learned Blender which is much more limited, someone else might be able to provide more insight on that though.)

Comment: AJ you are my hero.  Thanks so much for all of your help.  So far so good, but silly question, what do I do to make it an mpeg after I create it??  Do I flatten or merge?  I'm so sorry.  I'm lost.  I do have the text and video up there, at least!

Comment: I am trying to render it in the render under compositions, but it keeps telling me there are errors.

Comment: @aleda - you should only have to add the finished composition to the render queue.  Set best settings and then for the encoder, choose the format you need and specify your render options.  It will then export the whole thing when you run the queue.  Alternately you could also open the project in Adobe Media Encoder and tell it which composition you want to render.  Adobe Media Encoder is probably a slightly more user friendly way to go if you aren't familiar with the intimate details of AE as AE can get pretty advanced.  I don't recall how advanced Media Encoder was in CS4 though.

Comment: What is it saying are the errors?

Comment: mismatch between  output module settings and transcode settings

Comment: property data invalid

Comment: I think I can only save it as a mov file.  Is this meaning that I don't have anything to run an mpeg file?

Comment: @Aleda - There are mpeg encoders included with it.  You have to choose the format from the option below quality level though.

Comment: It's when I do that that I get the error.

Comment: @aledapowell - based on the description, it sounds like your composition has a different aspect ratio or resolution than you are specifying in the encoder.  Can you post a screen shot of the settings you are configuring in the encoder options?

Comment: Umm....I've never done that.  :~)  never needed to.